# Como carregar CSS ao utilizar URL Amigável no Apache?

Tags: php, html5, htaccess

Meu CSS não carrega o conteúdo quando passei a utilizar a URL amigável. Tente utilizar a **tag** `<base href="localhost/guiacomercial/" />` e dentro do **.htaccess** `RewriteBase /`

Pois o carregamento fica assim de qualquer forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue o código do .htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^es/guarapari\/?$ cidade.php?acessando=contato [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notei que está utilizando HTTPS também.
Não sei se já está fazendo desta forma, porém acredito que você possa tentar incluir o arquivo **.css** através da URL absoluta.

Ex.:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://localhost/guiacomercial/path_to_css/estilo.css">
```